# Value of type "localSearch" has no member "start"?

Tags: swift, error-handling, member, separator

I'm having this issue in Xcode 7.3.1. I'm essentially adding a search bar to a map. Here's the first part of the code for context:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

var searchController:UISearchController!
var annotation:MKAnnotation!
var localSearchRequest:MKLocalSearchRequest!
var localSearch:MKLocalSearch!
var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!
var error:NSError!
var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation!
var pinAnnotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!

@IBAction func showSearchBar(sender: AnyObject) {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()

    let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 47.6062, longitude: -122.3321)

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
                                                                  regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }

    centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Here's the snippet where the error occurs:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar){
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    if self.mapView.annotations.count != 0{
        annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0]
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }
    localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
    localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
    localSearch.start{ (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in
        if localSearchResponse == nil{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Place Not Found", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
```

At `localSearch.start`, I am getting:

> "Value of type MKLocalSearch has no member start"

I'm fairly new to Swift and pretty confused as to what the error is.

I also get:

> "expected separator ",""

in the 3rd to last line. But even when changing it, error continues to occur. Could the two be related?

Comment: Try cleaning the project and run the code again , your code looks fine

Comment: @3stud1ant3 cleaned and tried to run, build failed :/ Should I include more code preceding this? Though I don't see any errors there..

Comment: yes please add some more code, are you using swift 2 or swift 3

Comment: I think for old version of swift , you can use `localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler`

Comment: I added the earlier code. I'm in version 2.2. I tried the mentioned modification but unsure what to actually add for the completion handler?

Comment: just replace `search` with `startWithCompletionHandler` in your original code and try running the code ,keep the other code as it is

Comment: Great that fixed it thanks! Any idea about the separator? I tried modifying it as it asked but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you please explain more about the separator error? I couldnt understand

Comment: In 3rd to last line, it wants me to use "," right before default, instead of "." But when I change it, it causes more error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using older version of `swift` (swift 2.2) so I think you need to

replace

```
localSearch.start { ...     //this is for swift 3
```

with

```
localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { ...   //this is for swift 2.2
```

For the error `,` of separator try this:

```
UIAlertActionStyle.Default
```

instead of

```
UIAlertActionStyle.default
```

Note : I think you also need to change `UIAlertControllerStyle.alert` to `UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert`